# Recovering from out of memory failure

Tags: c++, embedded, heap-memory

I am using a memory pool to create a lot of objects. All my objects derive from a Base class which has its new/delete over ridden to use my memory pool, basically they call pool.allocate(size).

What I would like to do is when the pool runs out of memory (there is still available memory in the system to function) I would like to set everything back to the beginning. I am thinking of setting a label right after main and goto label when allocation fails, reset the pool and start again.

All non stack allocation are handled by the memory pool. Is this a sensible way to achieve this? Are there gonna be any problems down the line?

EDIT:

This is running on an embedded platform so no OS no exceptions. I am trying to achieve a controlled restart instead of a crash from out of memory. Pool is big enough to hold calculations, I am trying to have a controlled crash in case some functions goes awry.

There is no state to be saved from run to run. I am trying to achive the process of hitting the reset button with software. So I can reset back to start of main notify the app about the restart.

Comment: _"reset the pool and start again"_ - What with already allocated items? Can't the pool just add (allocate) an extra block and add a new item there?

Comment: @Danny_ds, This is running on an embedded system, when the pool runs out it means something messed up and it is gonna crash a little later anyways. better to reset everything back to start and give it another chance to run.

Comment: Given it's embedded, do you even have an OS? Can you just restart the task when it runs out of memory?

Comment: Are there any problems?  Not if can do something to stop your software from being deployed in the next car I buy.

Comment: @slugonamission, no os, it is running bare bones. Thats why I am trying to achieve a controlled crash.

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya - Ah, I thought there was still memory available.

Comment: The techniques to do that are going to depend very much on your hardware - particularly the processor and the means by which memory is managed (e.g. the MMU  if your processor implements one).   Your design also comes into play - for example, do the objects have some sort of state that needs to survive a restart, if so can they be saved to some persistent memory when a problem occurs?  Can the system user tolerate the time to save objects [if needed] power cycle, and reload?   Is it better running two instances, and fail over to the other?

Comment: @Hans Passant , so you want your car to crash suddenly, instead of a controlled restart.  which is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Trying to not kick in an opened-door: it is entirely up to you to determine what a controlled restart looks like.  There is no general advice.

Comment: Easier than any C++ trickery would be to just jump to the microcontroller's reset vector, starting you from square one.  Or, if you have peripherals you'd like to reinitialize also, many micros have an on-board watchdog timer: when you want to reset initialize it but don't kick it and it will take you off to reset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once did a similar thing using `setjmp()/longjmp()`. It's not perfect or devoid of problems, but, for the most part it works. Like:

```
jmp_buf g_env;

int main()
{
    int val = setjmp(g_env);
    if (val) {
        // restarting, do what you need to do
    }
    // initialize your program and go to work
}

/// where you want to restart:
    longjmp(g_env, 101); /// 101 or some other "error" code
```

This is a `goto` really, so, remember to do any cleanup yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing which comes in mind is throwing an exception. This is actually how default implementation of `operator new` behaves: it throws `std::bad_alloc`.

`goto` will work only if whole your program is limited to a single function. I see possible implementation of `main` as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            do_things(argc, argv);
        } catch(const MyBadAlloc& ex) {
            do_cleanup();
            continue;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I know thats how regular new behaves but this is running on an embedded system it does not have exceptions. Thats why I am thinking about using goto as a work around.

Comment: It is a big surprise to me that there is an implementation of C++ without exception support. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: It isn't a matter of the c++ implementation, it's a matter of not being willing to take the hit on exceptions for an embdedded platform, or trying to not explode on non-exception safe code. -fnoexceptions    Many developers, including games and embedded explicitly turn them off.